# MarkLogic multiple parameters in HTTP extension with operator

Tags: rest, parameters, marklogic, operator-keyword

I have MarkLogic REST extension for the GET function which accepts a String to perform word match search.

When I use `/v1/resources/{module}?rs:q=bri+OR+ade`, MarkLogic interprets "`bri OR ade`" as one param:

---

```
title:  "bri OR ade"
result: null
```

---

Is there any way that I can make the service extension works just as smart as `/v1/search?q=Brit+OR+Adele`?

Comment: If this is a custom REST endpoint, can you post the code in your question? It helps to see what you are doing with the parameter value to execute your search.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to suggest changes without seeing your actual code. However, if you are simply using the value of the parameter to execute a search:

```
cts:search(doc(), $q)
```

Then it will generate a word query for that phrase: `cts:word-query("bri OR ade")`

**You could use the [`cts:parse()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.parse) function to parse the `$q` request param and generate the desired query criteria:**

```
cts:search(doc(), cts:parse($q))
```

which would then produce the following query:

```
cts:or-query((cts:word-query("bri", ("lang=en"), 1), cts:word-query("ade", ("lang=en"), 1)), ())
```

**To constrain the search to the `firstname` property, use the [`cts.jsonPropertyScopeQuery()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.jsonPropertyScopeQuery) function:**

```
cts.search(cts.jsonPropertyScopeQuery("firstname", cts.parse(customerName)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to pass a query expression, Mads suggests a good solution.

If the goal is to pass multiple criteria values for a single query constructor, does the q key have a list of values if the client repeats the rs:q HTTP query parameter? As in:

```
/v1/resources/{module}?rs:q=bri&rs:q=ade
```

Hoping that helps,

Comment: If the goals is to pass the query values as a single HTTP value, one approach would be to choose a character that doesn't appear in any of the values as a  delimiter, concatenate the values with the delimiter, and use fn:tokenize() or fn.tokenize() to split on the delimiter to get the values list.

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind sharing an example as of how that delimiter works? I am not clear if I should pass that delimiter in the HTTP rs:q or I should use fn.tokenize() in cts query module along with delimiter...

Comment: For instance, if the delimiter is the | character, the HTTP encoding is %7C, so the query parameter would be rs:q=bri%7cade and the call would be something like:
const wordList = fn.tokenize(...theValueOfQ, '|').toArray();